# When "With" begins a sentence, can it lead to a dangler?

Tags: grammaticality, dangling-modifiers

When grammar guides discuss dangling modifiers, they usually refer to dangling participles, probably because they are the commonest form of the error, but I'm confused about whether prepositional phrases can be danglers, too. Here's a good example that illustrates my confusion:

"With one wave of her magic wand, the mice turned into strong white horses."

Is this grammatical? I can't decide. The mice didn't wave the magic wand; the Fairy Godmother did, so I think the above should be recast as:

"With one wave of her magic wand, the Fairy Godmother turned the mice into strong white horses."

But, on the other hand, I suppose you could argue that the prepositional phrase *does* modify the whole of the main clause, and therefore the original is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: I'm not keen on the sentence, but I'd usually argue on first clarity and then style grounds for acceptability in cases like this. Pullum has argued that we can be too precious about the 'grammaticality' of 'misplaced modifiers'.

Comment: The whole shtick about dangling modifiers is nonsense. It's fine for people to have a stylistic preference to avoid them, but the "logical argument" typically used to justify the preference is linguistically rubbish. People use them, and there is very rarely any ambiguity in what they mean. Ergo, they are grammatical and normal, and arguments which purport to explain their ungrammatiality are hot air.

Comment: "With one wave of her magic wand" seems pretty clearly an adverbial clause modifying the entire main clause, so I don't see an issue. If it was attached to a subcomponent of the sentence, which subcomponent is it attached to?

Comment: @StuartF I thought it was attached to whatever subject immediately follows the comma, which, in the original sentence, is "the mice", who did not wave the wand, and therefore the sentence contains a dangler. It would be like if I wrote "With over 1,000 pieces, I found this jigsaw puzzle to be a challenge," instead of writing "With over 1,000 pieces, this jigsaw puzzle provides a challenge."

Comment: @JJ_Doogal That's one of the rules that people often try to find an unobvious subject. But it's not required; it's just common. Any way you can figure it out works. Like most details.

Comment: @JohnLawler So are you saying that avoiding dangling modifiers is not that important as long as the reader can find the subject with relative ease?

Comment: Yes, basically. It's not elegant, but it's understandable.